# コンパイルし直したscalaコードをreplを終了させないでrepl上で実行する方法

Tags: scala

sbt consoleを起動している場合
元のプログラムを変更してコンパイルし直しても　repl上ではこの変更が反映されていません。
今は :quitで一端終了させた後
改めてまたsbt consoleを起動させていますが、
この方法では前回のrepl上での状態(importしたファイルなど)をもう一回
入力し直さないといけません。
この手間をなくしたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala の REPL 内で `:load Scalaのファイルのパス` とするとそのファイルを読み込めるので、これを使って変更したプログラムを再度読み込むと良いと思います。

また、`:save パス` とすると、それまでにREPLに入力した内容がそのファイルに保存されます。
そして `:load saveしたパス` とすれば、REPL上での入力を繰り返さずに済みます。